# How to write contains query in SQLite fts3 fulltext search

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, fts3

I want to make fulltext search in my index table which is sqlite fts3.

For example;
the data set is  { "David Luiz", "David Villa", "Diego Costa", "Diego Ribas", "Diego Milito","Gabriel Milito", }

When I type "vid i" I want to get {"David Luiz", "David Villa"}

In documentation of SQLite I found this 
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3
but it contains just startswith query.

```
my query is:
   SELECT *FROM Table WHERE Table MATCH "*vid* *i*"
```

I dont know it is possible or not. If it is possible to make search in sqlite fts3, any help will be appreciated

Comment: you can try this : select * from Table_name where Column_Name like'%vid%'

Comment: I can write like queries but if it possible and match query do this on behalf of us, I want to learn match query and I want to make search "vid i" not "vid", maybe you simplfy my query but it is just example and I want to get texts that contains both vid and i together like da"VID" v"I"lla da"VID" lu"I"z

Comment: Post your related code of query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FTS index is optimized for word searches, and supports word prefix searches.

There is no index that can help with searches inside words.
You have to use `LIKE '%vid%'` (which scans the entire table).

Answer (score 3):

Change your query from

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table MATCH "*vid* *i*"
```

To

**`SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE some_column LIKE '%vid%'`**